# Listing All UI Element of Metro App Using Windows UI Automation On Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a Metro app. I am developing a automation client. I want to List All Element of the Metro App.

1. I am Launching the metro App through IApplicationActivationManager
2. I am getting the focussed element

   HRESULT hr = automation->GetRootElement(&pRoot);
   hr = automation->GetFocusedElement(&pFound);

Now I wanted  to List All the Control like button, Picture element and Other

I am Using FindAll of automation Interface to get element ,

```
    // Create a property condition for the button control type.   
    VARIANT varProp;  
    varProp.vt = VT_I4;  
    varProp.lVal = UIA_ButtonControlTypeId;  
    hr = automation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_ControlTypePropertyId, varProp, &pButtonCondition);   

    if (pButtonCondition == NULL)
        goto cleanup;

    // Create a property condition for the enabled property.
    varProp.vt = VT_BOOL;
    varProp.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;
    hr = automation->CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_IsEnabledPropertyId, varProp, &pEnabledCondition);
    if (pEnabledCondition == NULL)
        goto cleanup;


    // Combine the conditions.
    hr = automation->CreateAndCondition(pButtonCondition, pEnabledCondition, &pCombinedCondition);
    if (pCombinedCondition == NULL)
        goto cleanup;

    // Find the matching elements. Note that if the scope is changed to TreeScope_Descendants, 
    // system buttons on the caption bar will be found as well.
    hr = pParent->FindAll(TreeScope_Children, pCombinedCondition, &pFound);
```

This Only List Button there in the metro app.
I wanted to List all the control on the Window.
Please help on this. How Can Get All Element of a Metro App?

Comment: metro isn't metro anymore
http://gizmodo.com/5931381/windows-metro-isnt-metro-anymore

Comment: @ClintonWard Do you know new name for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it out ......If we use true condition we can find all element on UI

```
IUIAutomationCondition* pCombinedCondition = NULL;
 hr = automation->CreateTrueCondition(&pCombinedCondition);
if (pCombinedCondition == NULL)
    goto cleanup;
// Find the matching elements. Note that if the scope is changed to TreeScope_Descendants, 
// system buttons on the caption bar will be found as well.
hr = pParent->FindAll(TreeScope_Children,pCombinedCondition , &pFound);
```